# Form: How to nest several forms?

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe

Ich I have a sub-form

```
% Form02
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=Two,width=5cm,]{Form 02:}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to put that in the main form?

```
%Form01
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=One,width=5cm,]{Form 01:}
 \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{Form02} % does not work
\end{Form}

\includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{Form02} % does not work
\end{document}
```

Comment: No. Such a form is an annotation (/Subtype/Widget) and annotations get lost when included as graphics.

Comment: Ah ok................

Comment: But it does work, if I use `\includestandalone[mode=tex]{Form02}`, or not?